# Animate transform a part of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, transform, nsattributedstring

Suppose I have a text like this: "Meet me today at 3 p.m", and I want to animate zoom the "today" part from original size to x1.2 then back (just a visual effect to attract the user attention to that part of the text).

How do I achieve this? The simple solution is to use 3 separated labels and animate  CGAffineTransformMakeScale for the middle label, but that's a horrible solution, as it's very difficult to do this when the text changes (for example, when we localize it into other languages).

Comment: I would use CATextLayer for that

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is using `NSAttributedString` and refresh label by using `CADisplayLink`. Something like this:

```
CADisplayLink *timer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animatePartOfText)];
    [timer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

-(void)animatePartOfText
{
    //calculate the size
    CGFloat size = 0 ;//......
    self.textLable.attributedText = [self makeTextWithPartSize:size];
}

-(NSAttributedString*)makeTextWithPartSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    NSAttributedString *firstPart = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Meet me " attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}];
    NSAttributedString *animatedPart = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"today" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:size]}];
    NSAttributedString *lastPart = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" at 3 p.m" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]}];
    NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:firstPart];
    [text appendAttributedString:animatedPart];
    [text appendAttributedString:lastPart];
    return text;
}
```

I am not sure about the performance, but it should work.

Comment: Your method is returning NSString,it should return NSMutableAttributedString. Like: -(NSMutableAttributedString*)makeTextWithPartSize:(CGFloat)size